# How to migrate Google Apps email?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I want to migrate my Google Apps account to another Gmail account.

Is this possible to migrate it?

Answer (score 2):

Open your new Gmail account and under Mail Settings -> Accounts and Import, choose Import Mail and Contacts.

Put your Google Apps account credentials and import.

Comment: imporing of already received emails is not possible by this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/search?query=migration+free+domain at google marketplace. Tool to migrate Gmail from one google domain to another.

Comment: Please expand on this answer. Which tool within the link you provided would do it? Is there a specific tool within those results that they should use? Also include any disclosure you need to like your affilation to the tool you're suggesting.